# Cannot bind parameter 'orchestrationContext' to type DurableOrchestrationContext while using DurableOrchestration with Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions, azure-triggers

I am trying to use the new Durable Functions extension in Azure Functions I installed this Nuget package on my Function project:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask

And then used the DurableOrchestrationContext in my function like that:

```
[FunctionName("StopVM")]
public static void StopVM([TimerTrigger("0 */2 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context, DurableOrchestrationContext orchestrationContext)
    {
    ....
    }
```

but when i run the function this error shown:

> Error indexing method 'FuncApp.StopVM' [20/11/2018
>   17:09:01] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method
>   'FuncApp.StopVM'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot
>   bind parameter 'orchestrationContext' to type
>   DurableOrchestrationContext. Make sure the parameter Type is supported
>   by the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure
>   Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the
>   registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g.
>   builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(),
>   builder.AddTimers(), etc.).

Do i missing some steps like adding any middle-ware to startup class or etc. cause the documentation not shown clearly how to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it. You should wrap your parameter of type `DurableOrchestrationClient` with this attribute`[OrchestrationClient]` if you want it to start the Orchestration itself or wrap the parameter of type `DurableOrchestrationContext` with this attribute  `[OrchestrationTrigger]` to use the context and here there are more details ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/functions-recipes/durable-setup))